# AppleScript's tell statement unconditionaly opens firefox, ignoring enclosing if block

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm experiencing the following issue

the script

```
osascript <<EOF
if false  is true
tell application "Firefox" to activate
end if
EOF
```

will open/activate Firefox unconditionally, ignoring the enclosing `if` block. Any other statement inside the if block is (correctly) ignored.

If the application to open is anything *But* firefox, the statement is correctly ignored.

I.E - the following statement is ignored correctly

`tell application "calculator" to activate`

The issue is not exhibited when running from Script Editor, only via `osascript`

Is Firefox exclusively handled somehow by AppleScript? How do I overcome this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

**Firefox** does not support **AppleScript** in that it does not contain an **AppleScript** dictionary *file*, no e.g. **Firefox.sdef** in its **Resources** *folders* within its *application bundle*, and only supports some of the basic *commands* of the **Standard Suite**.

To keep  **Firefox** from opening with the *code* shown in your OP, you'll need to tokenize (set as a *variable*) its `name`, as in the following *example*:

```
osascript <<EOF
if false is true
set appName to "Firefox"
tell application appName to activate
end if
EOF
```

**Or:**

```
osascript <<EOF
if false is true
set |Firefox| to "Firefox"
tell application |Firefox| to activate
end if
EOF
```